# Assign a path: like Amiga OS

Tags: command-line

On the good old days, when I used to use a Amiga computer, i used a command : "ASSIGN" to not make a new directory. Now I need a such command in UBUNTU, and I don't find a such command. And I need to put it on startup and I don't know how either.

Mvh Moi

---

Format
ASSIGN [:{dir}] [FROM ] [TO ] [LIST]
[EXISTS] [DISMOUNT] [DEFER] [PATH] [ADD] [PREPEND] [REMOVE] [VOLS]
[DIRS] [DEVICES] [NOREQ]

So describes in wikipedian, could it help ?

Comment: It may be helpful if you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1341255/edit) and describe what ASSIGN does. Not many of us have used an Amiga :-) Have a look at this for startup applications https://linuxhint.com/manage-startup-programs-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: After reading your comment about programmers in your profile, I do not feel inclined to help you anymore. What an attitude! And you are using Open Source software given to you for free by programmers?

Comment: The assign command was kinda like an alias for paths.  So you could do thing like `assign doc: HD0:documents/home/myproject/txtfiles` and then access the files in that path with things like `vim doc:readme.txt` also worked from the GUI not just the shell.

Answer (score 0):

I miss the ASSIGN command from the Amiga as well.  I have made a bash script that does something close.

https://github.com/TheBeef/AmigaAssign

If you source the script at startup and it will add an `assign` command to bash.  You can then assign env vars to paths.

Add a new env var using `assign workdir /home/user/work`.  It remembers them between sessions.  You then use them by doing things like `cd $workdir`.  Works with auto complete as well.

Only works in the shell however, won't work from the GUI.

Comment: Thank you Paul.  I knew  it may be a way  do it :-)